# Is calling Hibernate Session.save() from within Entity an Anit-Pattern?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence, hibernate-entitymanager

I've recently come across a legacy code base that uses a slightly dated version of Hibernate. The codebase uses the good old `[HibernateUtil][1]` pattern. One thing I find really odd is that every entity class has a `create()`,`read()`, `save()`, and `update()` method. All of these method are static and make calls to the static methods on the home-grown HibernateUtil class.

I don't like this pattern from a maintainability perspective and a few other obvious reasons, but I do recall this type of pattern to be a Hibernate, or EntityManager anti-pattern. But for the life of me, I can't find any specific details on why it's bad. I vaguely recall some issues with transaction semantics, etc., but cannot recall. Does anyone recall why this is/was considered a bad design pattern?

Comment: If update methods were not static I'd call it `ActiveRecord` pattern https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html